# database choice to implement a program to retrieve top 10 voted question in a live session

Tags: redis, cassandra, nosql

I am implementing a program that will let people to ask questions during a webinar and vote on questions. These questions can be upto 5 millions in total for an hour long webinar. And each question can have 1-100 votes. I am exploring options to select a right database and processing engine to calculate top 10 questions. Based on my understanding cassandra can meet some of the needs like fast writes and incremental data. I can partition on questionid (primary key) and timeuuid (cluster key) (for each vote). I can also have a counter static filed for vote count for each question.
Where I am stuck is to find top 10 questions across all these partitions. Cassandra does not support this query. Could anyone please share thoughts on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I will give an example for redis. It can be achieved in a single sorted set or a sorted set + hash.

You can keep the votes in the `score` of sorted sets and question as the `member`. Whenever increase the vote, you call [ZINCRBY](https://redis.io/commands/zincrby) to increment the score(votes) of the question. When you want to fetch top voted n questions you use [ZREVRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/zrevrange).

Here is the demo for a single sorted set;

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY votes 1 "my question"
"1"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY votes 1 "my question"
"2"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY votes 1 "my question"
"3"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY votes 1 "my another question"
"1"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY votes 1 "my another question"
"2"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY votes 1 "yet another question"
"1"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY votes 1 "my question"
"4"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY votes 1 "yet another questionssss"
"1"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANGE votes 0 2 WITHSCORES
1) "my question"
2) "4"
3) "my another question"
4) "2"
5) "yet another questionssss"
6) "1"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Another combination is sorted set with hash. Questions are kept in the hash. You need to generate id for the questions in the hash. when you `ZINCRBY`, you use question id as the member. Then when you need to fetch the top voted n questions you use `ZREVRANGE` to get the ids and then use [HMGET](https://redis.io/commands/hmget) to get questions of the given ids.

Comment: Thanks @Ersoy, Do you see any challenge in storing 40m entries in a sorted list?

Comment: according to the your needs total number of elements in the sorted set is not a problem. sets can keep billion elements. both ZINCRBY and ZREVRANGE can work in log(n) complexity (it is not o(1)) - so it couldn't be a problem but you may need to benchmark by filling it some dummy data. the response time of the sorted set with 10 and 10 million may not be same for both incrby and range queries.  @Pragmatic